# How does google+ protect the api-key embedded inside ios apps?

Tags: ios, google-plus

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys states that:

> Create and use an iOS key if your application runs on iOS devices. Google verifies that each request originates from an iOS application that matches one of the bundle identifiers you specify. An app's .plist file contains its bundle identifier. Example: com.example.MyApp

Does this mean that the google APIs (server-side) somehow verify/ensure that only my app can use this key? Or, does it just mean that the iOS libraries that google provides will do a sanity check before accepting the api-key? Is there anything to prevent a malicious user from decompiling my iOS app and re-using this api-key within his own app (making direct HTTP calls without using google iOS libraries)?

Extending this to the api-key used in browsers - the only protection seems to be the Referer check against a whitelist of domains. Is there anything stopping a malicious app developer from taking my api-key from the browser and using it within his native app (which sets a fraudulent Referer header)?

Answer (score 0):

So basicly you are correct the api key is mendetory because only you/your app should have access. But the fact is that everyone with your api key is can have access. And the play store has a big issue with not hidden api keys
http://www.cnet.com/news/thousands-of-secret-keys-found-in-android-apps/

for the second question I have no Idea sorry